# product of two numbers ending in 6 also ends with 6

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We have to prove that

"the product of two numbers ending in 6 also ends with 6" mathematically.

I have no clue how to start. I don't want you to prove it for me! but some hints would be very helpful as I'm totally stuck on how to start this prove.

Comment: Do you know anything about modular arithmetic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT: If $a$ ends in $6$, then $a=10m+6$ for some integer $m$. If $b$ also ends in $6$, then $b=10n+6$ for some integer $n$. Now what’s $ab$?

Comment: thx for your hint! i got it! thx

Comment: @gosua: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

think of it as multiplying the two units of the 2 numbers first: 6 and 6. you will get 36. Then if you add the multuplications of the other digits, no matter what you add on to 36, the 6 at the end will never change because all the multiplications have a number that is a multiple of ten.

Example: 26x16

lets do 6x20 we get 120, or we could do 20 x 10 and we get 200.

Notice that no matter what multiplication you except for 6x6 do you'll always end up with a 0 at the end. And if you add all these numbers together, you'll get a 0 at the end.

and then you add 6x6 which is 36 and you'll always get a 6 on the end